# Does pep8 fail to recognize `# noqa` in some instances?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

For readability reasons, I prefer to align some types of statements, such as in the following case (this involves some PyParsing code, but that detail doesn't matter):

```
_otherwise_stmt = _OTHERWISE ('otherwise statement')
_else_stmt      = _ELSE      ('else statement')
_end_stmt       = _END       ('end statement')
```

For this, `pep8` complains about E221 ("multiple spaces before operator") and E211 ("whitespace before '('").  If I put `# noqa` at the end of every one of the lines, `pep8` *still* complains about these lines.  However, for other constructs elsewhere in my file, the `# noqa` works as expected.  I'm confused about why `# noqa` does not make `pep8` work as expected for these particular constructs.

Is this a bug in the `pep8` program, or am I doing something else wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pep8` script only lets you disable specific error codes with a `# noqa` comment.

See the [*Error Codes* table](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes); only error codes marked with `(^)` can be silenced this way. E211 and E221 are not among them (none of the E2* codes are):

> `(^)` These checks can be disabled at the line level using the `# noqa` special comment. This possibility should be reserved for special cases.

Personally, I prefer using the [`flake8` tool](http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which combines `pep8` with PyFlakes, and lets you use the `# noqa` marker far more liberally.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/issues/180) ("*# noqa not honored for most Errors*"), depending on who you ask.

The tool does allow you to use `# noqa` for some warnings but not for `E221` and `E211`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flake8 --ignore=E2xx` for ignoring any of the E2* codes since `# noqa` doesn't ignore them.